# Uncaught Error, object is not a function for this.state

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I am getting an error at `this.state`:

```
constructor () {
  super()
  this.state = {
    resultText: ""
  }
  this.buttonPressed = this.buttonPressed.bind(this)
}

buttonPressed(input)
{
  console.log(input)

  if (input == '='){
    return this.calculateResult()
  }

  this.setState= ({
    resultText : this.state.resultText+input
  })
}
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

This is syntax error, just change:

```
this.setState= ({
  resultText : this.state.resultText+input
})
```

to

```
this.setState({
  resultText : this.state.resultText+input
})
```